# R if statement to return NULL when data not available

Tags: r, if-statement, null

I am trying to create an if statement so that when `filter(OD > threshold_1)%>%` is not found or does not exist in `df`it returns "NULL" instead of what is being returned currently...

```
library(dplyr)

find_time = function(df, threshold_1, threshold_2, ODf){
    return_value_1 = df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD > threshold_1) %>%
    slice_(1)
    colnames(return_value_1)[1] <- "time_hdt_upper"
    colnames(return_value_1)[2] <- "OD_hdt_upper"

    return(data.frame(return_value_1))
}
```

returns:

```
[1] time_hdt_upper OD_hdt_upper  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names
```

Thus I would like it to return `NULL` if `return_value_1` is not available, as such:

```
time_hdt_upper OD_hdt_upper

  NULL            NULL
```

In other words, I want: `#if return_value_1[1,1] equals NA set return_value_1[1,1] and return_value_1[1,2] to "NULL"`

I have tried a combination of:

```
  find_time = function(df, threshold_1){
    return_value_1 = df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    filter(OD > threshold_1) %>%
    slice_(1)
    colnames(return_value_1)[1] <- "time_hdt_upper"
    colnames(return_value_1)[2] <- "OD_hdt_upper"

    if(OD %>% threshold_1 %in% df) {return("no threshold")}

    return(data.frame(return_value_1))
}
```

returns error:

```
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'OD' not found
Called from: eval(lhs, parent, parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have your if statement look at `return_value`:

```
if (nrow(return_value) == 0) {
    return (NULL)
} else {
    return(return_value)
}
```